# Mouse eventlistener behaving abnormal on Edge and Safari compared to FireFox and Chrome, any idea why?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mouseevent

So I have this issue with my canvas animation js. Basically, every time there is mouse movement my code creates to js objects and pushes to the array to be animated. It's behaving as expected on Chrome and Firefox, but very abnormal on Safari and Edge. I know that they have different engines, but the difference in object creation is vast. You can check out from my github source code, filename is canvas.js and you will need canvastag on your html. Here is the part that I am mentioning:

```
window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
        init(event.x, event.y, 40);
        init(event.x + random(5, 10), event.y+random(5, 10), 40);
});
```

**Here is the link to hosted project on GH-pages:** https://rpaltayev.github.io/js-canvas/

Here is  the source code from my github: github: https://github.com/rpaltayev/js-canvas

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No, we can't rely on external resources. You need to include all information necessary in your question itself. For javascript debugging questions, you can create a [Code Snippet (`<>` icon)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) and include an [MCVE]. Also, it would be good to say what version of the browsers you are experiencing it with, since you are using a relatively new property of the MouseEvent (`clientX` should have better support in older browsers).

Comment: Sorry, it's not external source it's from my own github repo.

Comment: But here we are on `https://stackoverflow.com`, `https://github.com` **is** an external resource ;-) We need to have everything needed to reproduce your issue from the question itself. Here if I copy what you gave I'll just have a TypeError because I don't know what `init` is => I don't have enough info to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I understand that, but unfortunately to reproduce I would just have to copy almost everything. The whole canvas.js script is like 100 lines of code and to exactly see the issue you just have to see the website. Just try the following link on edge and chrome. It's hosted on gh-phages already: https://rpaltayev.github.io/js-canvas/

Comment: Sorry to be blind-minded, no offense whatsoever, but you are saying that it is too much work for you to create a minimal example, or to go through the hundreds of lines in your code, but you would like us to do so? It doesn't work like that no. And FYI, the minimalistic example would be `onmousemove = event => console.log(event.x, event.y);` no need to draw anything if it is indeed here that there is a problem. And if the problem is somewhere else, then show only this somewhere else.